# Opportunity attacks and immediate interupts per round

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, actions, immediate-actions

I read this in an [online article](http://dungeonsmaster.com/2011/06/opportunity-attacks/), which sounded incorrect to me.

> The Fighter takes his free attack and gets all the additional bonuses that come with Combat Superiority. Needless to say, my monsters get hit more often than not for taking this action. A hit inflicts damage and stops their movement. Then, as my standard action I charge away from the Fighter and attack someone else. Since the Fighter has already taken an opportunity attack against me I can now get away Scott free [[sic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scot-free)].

As combat challenge is an immediate interrupt and not an opportunity attack, doesn't that mean you could make BOTH an opportunity attack and a combat challenge attack on the same target in the same turn?

I believe the way to avoid both attacks would instead be to shift (move action), provoking the combat challenge attack, and to attack the 2nd target, because I'd be out of range of the fighter's opportunity attack.

Is this correct, have I missed anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, a Fighter can take both an Opportunity Attack and an Immediate Interrupt on the same turn.**

> **Immediate Actions** (Rules Compendium 195)
>
> Once per Round: A creature can take only one immediate action per round, either an immediate interrupt or an immediate reaction. Therefore, if a creature takes an immediate action, it can’t take another one until the start of its next turn.
>
> **Opportunity Actions** (Rules Compendium 196)
>
> An opportunity action is similar to an immediate interrupt, but it can be taken once per turn, rather than once per round.

You get 1 opportunity action per turn (except on your own turn) and 1 immediate action per round (except on your own turn). These are different things and taking one doesn't impede on another.

In fact, if you were a fighter and marked an adjacent enemy and that enemy made a ranged attack on an ally, that one attack would trigger BOTH your opportunity attack (because it was a ranged attack) and your immediate interrupt (because it was an attack that didn't include you). Two swings for the price of one!

In terms of getting *away* from the fighter, shifting and eating the immediate interrupt is probably your best bet, because Combat Challenge doesn't stop the movement.

Note that once you trigger one of the two attacks, you're safe against *that* attack: so if you try to move and you get stuck by the opportunity attack, you can convert your standard to a move or make a charge since the OA is used and moving doesn't trigger CC. It sounds like the excerpt you're quoting describes such a case, but I don't see what action triggered the fighter's free attack as described in that bit.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a little confused... although that explanation did still help some. If CC can target enemies that make attacks not targeting the Fighter, shouldn't a charge provoke CC, as it is an attack and a standard, not a move action? Or does it not count as the individual who charged does not make the actual attack component of the charge until after he has left the fighters threat zone? Thanks again

Comment: @user7643 That would probably be better as a separate question, no? It's a specific case rather than this general question about OAs and immediate actions.

Comment: Charge basically says "move your speed and make a basic melee attack" thus it has a move component and an attack component, but each triggers when it happens. The attack from a charge only happens after the movement.